# how to compress the media from admin using django compressor

Tags: django-compressor

i am using django-compressor and in the admin/change_form.html i have the following lines of code

```
{% change_media_list media as media_list %}
{{ media_list|safe }}
```

This renders the following when i see it in the browser

```
<link href="/static/course_planner/css/season_tpl.css" type="text/css"media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery  /jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/dashboard /js/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.js">  </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/urlify.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js">  </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp /xregexp.js"></script>
```

Now I want to know is it possible to compress the admin media context and if so how?